# Visualizing Memory Usage in Single Channel vs Dual Channel Mode

Tags: memory

I am looking for a way to teach high school aged students (14-18) the difference between dual channel and single channel memory. We have the theory on paper and diagrams showing how it is mapped, but I was hoping for a testing tool that could be used to present how the memory is allocated and accessed differently with a visual graph, or data that could be plotted into a graph easily.

One consideration I had was recommending the instructor use [IOzone](http://www.iozone.org/) with a ramdisk. It will show the performance improvement, but I do not think it will show how the system maps the memory differently.

Any input would be helpful!

Comment: How does a diagram showing how it is mapped not say it all?  Well, I guess with the added statement that the two banks can be accessed at the same time.

Comment: @psusi I was hoping for a way to demonstrate it in a classroom environment aside from just the diagrams. Many students who gravitate towards this program tend to have learning disabilities, and being able to see the cause and effect of turning on dual channel would be beneficial instead of just showing a stale diagram. 

You can show them as many diagrams or flow charts as you want, but giving a visual demonstration on the difference (especially in an individual exercise lab) can help put the pieces together and make the concept "click".

Comment: What does "giving a visual demonstration on the difference" mean, if not showing the diagram?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of a graph that would show memory allocation by channel or the difference in performance with dual channel vs. single channel memory. Even a benchmark showing that the same test before and after doesn't swap to disk as much or can cache more would help.